react syntax highlighter not changing text fetched from github
I am using react-syntax-highlighter and trying to make the pr i pulled from github to look pretty but it does not work. Am I applying it wrong? Should I be applying it elsewhere?
Is there an alternative to it?
Picture of how it looks like rendering the pr from github
 const renderPRs = () => {
    console.log('Rendering PRs:', userPRs); 
    
    const userCreatedPRs = userPRs.filter(pr => pr.user.login === username);
  
    return userCreatedPRs.map(pr => (
      <div key={pr.id}>
        <a href={pr.html_url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{pr.title}</a>
        <p>State: {pr.state}</p>
        {prDiffs[pr.number] && (
          <SyntaxHighlighter language="diff" style={docco} className="diff-block">
  {prDiffs[pr.number]}
</SyntaxHighlighter>

        )}
      </div>
    ));
  };

.... more code here and then rendering the pr here, no tags around it or anything:
   {renderPRs()}

